# Supporting statement, competency evidence, cover letter

Tags: interviewing, resume, cover-letter

I am an international applicant, and I am applying for a teaching job in the UK. In the online application there is a section for competency evidence questions, and there is another section for uploading a supporting statement.
In the competency evidence part, I already describe my qualifications with examples regarding the position, I don’t know what exactly include in the supporting statement to avoid the repetition. I also wanted to know if the supporting statement is the same as the cover letter.
Thank you for your help,
M

Comment: It may vary by field but a supporting statement is generally for anything not covered in the other documents, so avoid repetition - although you can highlight specific skills if you feel they've not been fully advertised. Somewhat like a cover letter, but expectations on length may be different - it's hard to generalise without knowing the position, the duties, what's in the other parts of the application, etc.

Comment: The position is Senior Lecturer in Fine Art Painting.  After the competency evidence questions,  they want me to attach CV,  publications,  and supporting statement described as:  a  section  for you  to  highlight  your suitability and  setting  out  how you consider your personal  skills and experience  meet  the essential criteria  for the role. 
The point is answering the competency evidence questions already describe my suitability for the role …

Comment: Competency evidence
demonstrate how your specialist knowledge and qualifications match the role requirements 
Please provide evidence of how you plan, prioritise and manage resources effectively to achieve objectives 
Please provide evidence of your ability to collaborate and work effectively within a team and with diverse range of people 
Please provide evidence of your contribution to advancing professional practice, research or knowledge exchange in your area of expertise 
Please provide examples from your experience of teaching in relation to the person specification for the role

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure, the best place to search for answers would be

- Any available FAQ for the application / job opening application in the website.
- Any support / helpline contact for the organization (or any point of contact received through them)

You can also ask someone who is experienced in your field, if they had gone through the same process, about the details or particulars.

In my view, the competency evidence will be your experience certificates (work / training / learning - as applicable in your role / industry) and supporting statement is mostly references (who can confirm some things which you've stated in the application) - but that's my view and I do not have firsthand experience in this process/flow.

Comment: supporting statement described as:  a  section  for you  to  highlight  your suitability and  setting  out  how you consider your personal  skills and experience  meet  the essential criteria  for the role. 
The point is answering the competency evidence questions already describe my suitability for the role …

Comment: Competency evidence
Please demonstrate how your specialist knowledge and qualifications match the role requirements 
Please provide evidence of how you plan, prioritise and manage resources effectively to achieve objectives 
Please provide evidence of your ability to collaborate and work effectively within a team and with diverse range of people 
Please provide evidence of your contribution to advancing professional practice, research or knowledge exchange in your area of expertise 
Provide examples from your experience of teaching in relation to the person specification for the role